# Sharekit status sharing with Facebook, problems only after first login

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I am sharing an URL with sharekit facebook like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:someurl];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Some text"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

The first time this is shared, I am directed to the facebook login and I allow the app to post on my status. But then my status shows up empty in the share dialog.

If I close the app (fully) and restart, my login is in place and the content is shared beautifully. But right after the first login, it fails with an empty status. Did anyone experience this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that ShareKit does something odd when it temporarily stores the URL in a dictionary, and restores it later. It does some percent escape encoding, whereas it should just store the absoluteString of the URL.

Change line 174 in SHKItem.m from:

```
[dictionary setObject:[URL.absoluteString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"URL"];
```

to:

```
[dictionary setObject:URL.absoluteString forKey:@"URL"];
```

Maybe you need to fix this at some other places too, but this change seemed to get it working for me.

Comment: What an awesome catch. Thanks! This one was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fork and its instructions: https://github.com/dagerydoo/ShareKit